# inserir dados via javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tenho uma table com o botão INCLUIR contendo o seguinte código:

```
<td align="center"><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row(<?php echo($id_usuario); ?>, 0);" value="INCLUIR"></td>
```

O arquivo tabela.js contem a func add_row() com o seguinte código:

```
function add_row(pid_usuario,pdia_da_semana)
{
    var inicio=document.getElementById("inicio").value; 
    var fim=document.getElementById("fim").value;   
    window.alert('ENTROU'); 

    //INCLUIR_REGISTRO(pid_usuario, pdia_da_semana, inicio, fim);

    var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
    var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
    var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='inicio_row"+table_len+"'>"+inicio+"</td><td id='fim_row"+table_len+"'>"+fim+"</td><td align='center'> <input type='button' value='EXCLUIR' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

    document.getElementById("inicio").value=""; 
    document.getElementById("fim").value="";

}
```

Basicamente o que eu faço com o botão incluir é adicionar uma nova linha a table.
Então pensei.. Já que estou adicionando a linha porque não incluir o registro neste momento. 
Ai que entra a falta de experiência..Não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer a função `INCLUIR_REGISTRO()`.

Algum dos colegas com mais experiência poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Boa tarde ISAC.. Na função add_row eu incluo uma linha no objeto <TABLE >. Se você observar, quando gero a <tr> e a <td> elas tem IDS diferentes que foi passado pela variavel TABLE_LEN. Então eu gerei essa linha e agora quero GERAR O INSERT na devida tabela.

Comment: Correto. E o que quer dizer com registro? A função `INCLUIR_REGISTRO()` é suposto fazer o quê exatamente?

Comment: Ola.. a função INCLUIR_REGISTRO(pid_usuario, pdia_da_semana, pinicio, pfim) seria algo do tipo:  Insert into tabela (id_usuario, dia_da_semana, inicio, fim) values (pid_usuario, pdia_da_semana,pinicio, pfim). execsql;

Comment: Para isso é necessário utilizar Ajax e enviar os dados para a página de php que vai pegar neles inserir na tabela correspondente e retornar o resultado da operação

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia a todos..

Deixo aqui a solução para o problema proposto.

No arquivo tabela.js foi criada outra função que posto abaixo:

```
function incluir_registro(id_usuario,dia_da_semana,inicio, fim) {
    dia_da_semana + ' inicio..: '+ inicio + '  fim..: '+ fim);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'm_h_02_i_horario.php',
        data: {
            inserir_registro: 'inserir_registro',
            pid_usuario :id_usuario,
            pdia_da_semana: dia_da_semana,
            pinicio: inicio, 
            pfim: fim 
        }, success: function(response) {
            if(response=="success") {
                window.alert('SUCESSO ' + id_usuario);   
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Então a lógica fica da seguinte forma:

O botão na parte html chama a função add_row() com os parametros id_usuario e dia_da_semana.
A função add_row(id_usuario,dia_da_semana) por sua vez chama a função inserir registro(id_usuario,dia_da_semana,inicio, fim).

Minha dificuldade estava em fazer a função incluir_registro, pois sou muito fraquinho em ajax script. Não estava entendendo como o **$.ajax** funcionava.

Pelo que eu pude entender dessa função ela funciona do seguinte modo:

1. type : post **->** gera o evento post
2. url : 'm_h_02_i_horario.php' **->** é a pagina php que insere de fato o registro
3. data:{inserir_registro:'inserir_registro',pid_usuario:id_usuario, pdia_da_semana: dia_da_semana , pinicio : inicio, pfim : fim } **->** é onde os parametros são passados para a pagina url (m_h_02_i_horario.php)
4. `success:function(response){if(response=="success"){window.alert('SUCESSO ' + id_usuario)}}` **->** caso o .php seja executado corretamente executa o que esta nesta função

Espero que estas linhas possam ser útil a comunidade.

Abraços.